# Как убрать скроллер снизу на сайте html css

Tags: html, css

Я делаю сайт для собственных нужд, и когда я поставил фон появился скроллер, который не нужен, как его убрать. 
Вот он на фото:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код фона css:

```
background: url(image.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
background-size: cover;
```

Если что не понятно коментируйте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

html { overflow:  hidden; }
   div { height:  2000px; }
введите этот код в style в html.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте добавить в `css`

```
overflow: hidden;
```